# The equivalent of "distinct" in SOQL does not work

Tags: soql

I need to run a query but do not must return account id duplicated.

I followed these articles:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yzrIAA
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm

and this is my query: `SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Asset GROUP BY AccountId`

but this gives an error: `[MALFORMED_QUERY] Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id`

what do I need to change in my query to she works?

Comment: What exactly do you need the query to return? Do you need all assets, regardless of account? Do you just need the accounts that have assets? Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY`, every field that you give in the `SELECT` clause needs to either:

- Be used in an Aggregate Function (`COUNT()`, `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()`, etc...)
- Appear in the `GROUP BY` clause

Since you do neither with the `Id` field, Salesforce is complaining.

You can group by multiple fields, separated by commas (`GROUP BY AccountId, Name`). You almost never want to include the `Id` field from the object you're querying though. As each Id is unique in your org, grouping by the Id field would cause no records to be grouped together (making the aggregate functions useless).

What your final query will look like depends on what information you're trying to extract from the query.

- If you just want the distinct set of values contained in a field, `[SELECT MyField__c FROM MyObject__c GROUP BY MyField__c]` will do the trick
- If you want to count how many records there are for each field value, `[SELECT COUNT(Id), MyField__c FROM MyObject__c GROUP BY MyField__c]` is what you're looking for

Comment: thank you for your answer, this query returned what I need: SELECT Max(Id), AccountId FROM Asset GROUP BY AccountId